# Error during rebuilding ASMX Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I'm trying to publish my web service, i have already changed Build Action properties of .asmx file to "Compile" and Web.config to "None" but still i get following errors when im trying to rebuild solution:

```
Error   1   Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @ \MyVirtualCartWS\MyVirtualCartWS.asmx

Error   2   A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods   \MyVirtualCartWS\MyVirtualCartWS.asmx
```

both errors points .asmx file so here it is:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="MyVirtualCartWS.asmx.cs" Class="MyVirtualCartWS.MyVirtualCartWS" %>
```

Code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Collections;


namespace MyVirtualCartWS
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description MyVirtualCartWS
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class MyVirtualCartWS : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        #region Using LoggedUser

        [WebMethod]
        public LoggedUser AddUser(string _login, string _email, string _password)
        {
            LoggedUser lUser = new LoggedUser();
            lUser.AddUser(_login, _email, _password);
            return lUser;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public LoggedUser LogIn(string _login, string _password)
        {
            LoggedUser lUser = new LoggedUser();
            lUser.LogIn(_login, _password);
            return lUser;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have you set web.config to none for publishing?

Comment: I set it to none because i found topic where it was said that it might be solution..

Comment: Weird - I've just changed Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/" to "http://yahoo.com" and.. VS rebuild solution without errors, then I've closed VS open it again try to rebuil...  same errors again. By the way, after a successful rebuild I published service but have't received file .asmx any clue why?

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

should be uncomment first.